# ruby copy folder with subfolders to a target location

Tags: ruby, copy, directory, fileutils

I'm trying to copy a folder with all its subfolders from source to a destination folder.
The below code doesn't seem to do it. I'm able to copy just the files instead of subfolders by using

```
FileUtils.cp_r(Dir["/Volumes/TempData/Collects/Sasi/android/*.*"],"/Volumes/Data/Apps/android")
```

What is it that I'm missing?

```
require 'fileutils'
puts "operating_system"
operating_system = gets.chomp

    if operating_system == "android" then
     FileUtils.cp_r(Dir["/Volumes/TempData/Collects/Sasi/android/**"],"/Volumes/Data/Apps/android")
     puts "done"
    elsif operating_system == "ios" then
     FileUtils.cp_r(Dir["Volumes/Data/Apps/iOS/CX5/**"],"/Volumes/TempData/Collects/For_CS")
     puts "done"
    else 
     puts "do nothing"
    end
```

Answer (score 43):

It looks like the FileUtils.copy_entry method will copy a directory tree for you.
There is some information in the rubydoc : http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-copy_entry

There are lots of options (such as whether to preserve file ownership) but some quick testing shows that you can just pass the source and destination directories in like this:

```
FileUtils.copy_entry @source, @destination
```

Comment: Works for me, too.

Comment: Threadnecromancer, @sasi please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Although this works great, it's still better to wrap it around the begin-rescue block.